# Pass context variable to linkTo parameter

Tags: meteor, iron-router, spacebars

Let's say I have following Iron.Router's `linkTo` helper:

```
{{#each reports}}
  {{#linkTo route='reports' query='q=string' }}Reports{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

Is it possible to pass enclosing context variable directly to `linkTo` without constructing additional helper? Something like this:

```
{{#each reports}}
  {{#linkTo route='reports' query='q='+_id }}Reports{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

I'm aware I can define a helper, e.g. `getQuery`, that will `return 'q'+_id`, but is there a way to do this on the fly?

Comment: Instead of an specific `getQuery` helper for each link, you could create a global `concat` helper that concatenates any number of parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.  If you look at the [Spacebars source](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars-compiler/templatetag.js), you can see that the function `scanArgValue` (from line 204 onwards) only accepts a limited number of basic data types, like paths, variables and literals.  There's no facility for this sort of (even basic) calculation in Spacebars itself, so you need to be doing it in a helper.